# lcd TV: panels or driver limit capabilities?

Tags: reverse-engineering

For a LCD panel, if I found a board which offered 120hz refresh rate and 3d active shutter type display could I add it to the panel and could I then get this kind of performance out of the lcd panel or is the limits of the panel determined solely by the quality of the panel alone?

Note I am not asking about resolution as I am quite confident that this is in fact a hardware limitation but suspect that the speed with which those pixels can be switched could be enhanced with a better driver board.

Comment: ... if you are having power issues, why are you looking at display drivers? I can't make heads or tails out of your question, and it's off topic for multiple reasons.

Comment: I would suggest that you remove the first paragraph entirely, it is not salient to your question and actually obscures it.

Comment: Context is everything - note the tag - *reverse-engineering*. He's not asking to fix it, but in what ways it can be 'hacked.'

Comment: did not authorize edit of my question :( .the title clearly summerise my question details as to foundation of cause of question while not necessary build depth and scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An LCD panel is comprised of a glass substrate with transistors printed on it along with Si based driver chips that are bonded to the glass to driver the columns and rows.

So what you are calling drivers and driver boards are *NOT* really the drivers. You are looking at what is know as the controller, and that has no limits on the speed.  For the most part, the glass panel is matched to a given driver and the interconnect is through ACF (Anisotropic Conductive film).  Essentially, even if you could take the drivers off and replace them, it is unlikely you *could* find a replacement.

Aside from the possibility of doing it, and getting to the meat of your question. The panel is the limiting factor, in fact the transistor that charge and discharge the pixels are the limiting factor. Most LCD's are built with amorphous Silicon which has poor electron mobility, there are newer panels made from IGZO, but these have yet to make main stream volume production.

Comment: thank you.my mistake on component names.I was just hoping maybe having a better controler to drive it may have be able to grant me a higher quality display.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was posted before, and then deleted by Dave Tweed, but I do not accept the reason for which it was deleted:

I originally posted:

> 90% of LCD TVs or monitors going dead after a couple of years is the
>   fault of two or four capacitors on the power supply board. Many
>   companies rate these caps too tightly in hopes that they will go bad
>   right after warranty wears off. Look for bulged caps on the power
>   supply board, replace them with properly derated caps (say 25v; the
>   ones on there are probably rated 10v), and there's a pretty good
>   chance you will have fixed your problem.

And Dave Tweed commented on it, before deleting:

> You're answering the wrong question. THIS question is about controller
>   boards for the LCD panel, not about any power supply issues. In any
>   case, your advice is ow-quality. The AC current rating in electrolytic
>   capacitors is VERY important.

The original question starts with:

> I have a reasonable quality 32" LCD TV that **has a problem with its
>   power supply** system somewhere...having it serviced by a professional
>   will cost me more than the cost for some alternative boards I have
>   seen online

So, first, this question IS about power supply issues, and NOT about the LCD controller. The OP seems confused in his original question; he knows the problem is with the power supply, but is wondering if he can replace the controller board. My answer adds precisions as to what is most likely the actual issue. There is also the fact that the deletion comment also mentions the AC current rating of the caps, but the capacitors in question are DC decoupling caps, for which the main limiting factors are voltage rating and ESR (through maximum operating temperature).

So, very disappointed that an actually useful answer for the OP got deleted by a moderator that does not understand the original question, with no consultation of possibility of undeletion. I do not care if I get dislikes on my answer, or if someone else gets the actual answer, but deleting content because you interpreted the question and answer the wrong way is not the way to go. -1 for you, Dave Tweed.

Comment: I'm sorry but Dave was right to delete it, the first paragraph is a preamble and has nothing to do with the question. The title states the question and the second paragraph starts with "My question ...."

Comment: Then someone should edit the question, instead of deleting valid information. As the question is worded, there is no way to know what the OP really wants to know. You went with paragraph 2 and 3, I went with paragraph 1. Just to be clear, I am not flustered because my answer was deleted, but because if someone else was to search the forum for LCD TV power supply issues, my answer would most likely be the one to help them resolve it.

Comment: There isn't (or rather wasn't) a question in the first paragraph.

Comment: The entire premise for the question about LCD controller is because the OP somehow thought that servicing the existing power supply would cost him more than a brand new controller board. My answer proposed that servicing the power supply would actually be very cheap, thus making the rest of the question moot.

Comment: the title of this question indicates that I was trying to find out if I was correct in assuming the boards were the controlling factor in the performance of of my tv or if it was a matter of the material in the pannel itself. the first paragraph was giving a foundation as to why I was comming to question the point. while I do need to perform a fix either way as founded in this first paragraph my intent on the question was primarilly if it was possible to gain performance with a better processor.... that I could in fact service power supply myself was good advice thought should be a comment

Comment: The answer shouldn't have been deleted. If it answered the wrong question, the correct course would be a downvote. But let's move on. No need to dwell.